# Changed string has dots with exact match needed

Tags: sed

I have this in the `eq_names.txt` file:

```
VS.SuccCellUpdt.PageRsp+VS.SuccCellUpdt.ULDataTrans-VS.SuccCellUpdt.Reg.PCH-VS.SuccCellUpdt.Detach.PCH-VS.SuccCellUpdt.Other.PCH
```

and want to replace exact match only, but this command below, which I have to perform on the file

```
sed -i 's/\<VS\.SuccCellUpdt\>/67180371/g' /tmp/eq_names.txt
```

generates

```
67180371.PageRsp+67180371.ULDataTrans-67180371.Reg.PCH-67180371.Detach.PCH-67180371.Other.PCH
```

I escaped the dot in string and made exact match for the string but the output still matches. There should be no change.

I tried others:

```
sed -i "s/\<VS\.SuccCellUpdt\>/67180371/g" /tmp/eq_names.txt
sed -i 's/\<VS.SuccCellUpdt\>/67180371/g' /tmp/eq_names.txt
sed -i 's/"VS.SuccCellUpdt"/67180371/g' /tmp/eq_names.txt
```

All made changes. Is there any way to match exactly the string when the string also has dots?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: the output should be same as input since sed should do nothing, i.e. there was no exact match in string

Comment: Why should it not match?

Comment: The last example should _not_ match anything, though.

Comment: I guess it was a exact match but for me the match would be VS.SuccCellUpdt.PageRsp but sed has no way of knowing that. I can  not even give a seperator for the input strings since they could be a + or - or * or a / which are my operators in the input file. so if I can provide that to sed perhaps it will handle correctly?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah you are correct the last example did not make the changes as expected. I guess that is the answer. Thanks